# Better position accuracy with Android

Tags: android, gps, position

I a trying to create an application that will be able to guide people in a city, with points of interest. For this, I need the better accuracy I get, in order not to place POI where there is nothing...

To do this I use droidAR (it gives me a radar, and I can place my POI thanks to their coordinates). But the accuracy is so bad I can't see how this can used.

For exemple, to determine if I a close to a POI, I calculate the distance between it and my GPS position. It can be that, with a 10 meters accuracy given by Android when I place the POI, it is then 80 meters away when I try to find it.

SO I looked forward to find another position systems, I found :

- skyhook, which is supposed to give a more accurate position. With this, I took 1000 points and checked their distance to the last point, it is always moving and it was sometimes 300m away, so it seems even less precise. Maybe anyone could use it successfully ?

  - someone told me to use DCM algo (Direct Cosine Matrix), that can give me an accurate relative position (no problem for my use cases to do every positioninf relative to a start point). Some drones are using it, it could reach 1 meter accuracy. But I couldn't find any implementation or help with Android.

Did anyone succeed into using the android GPS with accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

Either your android phone has a bad GPS device, or more probably you are doing something wrong. you can set a POI in city aprox. 5m acuracy, sometimes 20m. that is sufficient. check it with another GPS app that allows setting a waypoint.

In your app you could concentrate on the 95% GPS accuracy. There is nothing better than GPS (espcecialla yon a mobile phone), the other methods you described are for short time assistance to GPS, but they will not work good for pedestrians, they are made for vehicles (vehicles move straight most of the times, they cannot change its direction so fast like a human does).

Your problem is not the GPS location accuracy, it is the augmented reality projection of droidAR.

Comment: The GPS may indeed sometimes reach such an accuracy. However according to google it isn't a determined accuracy, a 5 meters accuracy means only that you may at 67% be at 5 m of the given point.

Comment: The Radial 95% Error of GPS is about 3,5m in good conditions. in cities about 5m. Just set the waypoint and look at the google map. 8Google maps are usually accurate to some meters.) Then you see, that the positionas are accurate enough, as lomng as you are not inside a building. 20m is still sufficient for a waypoint, (dont forget) normal people find the point whithout GPS, too.

Comment: I don't use POI with google map but with droidAR. I have a kind of virtual world in 3 dimensions (with the camera) in which I can project my POI to show the user where they are. The first problem is that it look really bad, when the point is just in front of me but the phone says it is very far away. The second thing is that I want my program to be used indoor.. I know it isn't a good idea but it would be very great if I could !

Comment: Then your problem is not the lication accuracy, it is the droidAR projection